# I have a listbox. How do I select the 3rd item in the listbox out of many items?

Tags: forms, vb6, listbox, controls

I have a form with 10 listboxes on it.  I also have a command button.  How do I make it so that if I press the command button it will select the 3rd item of a listbox of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do so by converting your 10 listboxes into a control array.  If I remember correctly, you do so by specifying the same `Name` property and a unique, non-negative `Index` property for each one of the `ListBox` instances in your form.

Assuming you named all of your list boxes as `ListBoxArr` and set up the `Index` property so that the first listbox is 0, the second one is 1, etc. then you can write something like this

```
' Access the 6th list box and select the third item
' Remember, Index values are zero-based, so 0 is first item...
ListBoxArr(5).ListIndex = 2
```